# Hide <td> contents when the same as the <tr> above

Tags: jquery, html-table

Given a simple table like this:

I want to hide the  text when it's the same as the text in the row above.

I've tried this... but I'm **really** new to JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let previous = "*";
  $('.nodup').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (obj.html() == previous) {
      $(obj).hide();
    } else {
      previous = obj.html(); // "reset" the previous value?
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">one</td> show this td
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">one</td> hide this td
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">one
      <td> hide this td
        <td>3</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">two</td> show this td
    <td>7</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So it would look like this in the end...

```
one    5    7    3
       6    9    1
       3    8    3
two    7    3    1
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to loop thru the `$(".nodup")` elements using `filter`. If the text is the same with the `temp` variable (means same with prev one), return true. Assign new value for the `temp` and return false otherwise.

Set the `html` to an empty string and not remove it.

```js
var temp = null;
$(".nodup").filter(function(i, o) {
  var text = $(this).text().trim();
  if (text === temp) return true;

  temp = text;
  return false;
}).html("");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">one</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">one</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">one</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nodup">two</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I *thought* this wasn't going to work, but I forgot that in our ecosystem, we have to replace $ with $j. Your solution works perfectly, thanks!!!